# I can't load a simple template with simple path by AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Like in title, I can't load a template correctly. I can't understand where the problem is, the only error that I got is "Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /testingBlock.html"

Paths:

```
/mainDirOfTheProject
      /application
      /library
      /webroot
           /javascript: [angularjs.js, angular-route.js, app.js]
           index.html
           testBlock.html
```

HTML(index.html):

```
  <body ng-app="App" ng-controller="MainCTRL as ctrl">
          {{ctrl.nameApp}}
          <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
```

HTML(testingBlock.html):

```
   <h1>Just a test</h1>
```

Javascript (app.js):

```
    angular
    .module("App", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(config)
    .controller("MainCTRL", MainCTRL);



function MainCTRL($location){
    this.nameApp = "myApp";
}



function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider){ 

    $routeProvider
        .when("/",{
            templateUrl: "/testingBlock.html",
            controller: "MainCTRL"
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true, requireBase:false});

}
```

I sorted it out: the problem was that the routing doesn't accept HTML file but HTM file.
I tried with jQuery ajax call, and it was the same.

So the question is, why jQuery ajax call doesn't accept .html files?

Comment: In the directory tree you posted the file is named `testBlock.html` and in your app config it's `testingBlock.html` at least.

Comment: @Fissio I did wrong in here, but on my project they match

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a dot in front of the slash :

```
templateUrl: "./testBlock.html",
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to load it relative to the path of your main index.html, try:

```
templateUrl: "testBlock.html",
```

If that doesn't work, watch the network tab in your browser dev tools and see what path it's trying to load your template from, and adjust as needed.